# About decimals and exponents

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, truncation-error

I was reading about the speed of convergence of iterative methods. Then I came across the following.

[image]
How is it inferred here that "At least
126 terms are needed to ensure this accuracy for the linearly convergent sequence"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linearly converging sequence is $(0.5)^n$.  To solve
$$  (0.5)^n = 10^{-38}  \text{,}  $$
take logarithms to the base $2$ on both sides
$$  -n = -38 \log_2 10 = -126.233\dots  \text{.}  $$
So, $(0.5)^n$ is a bit larger than $10^{-38}$ for $n = 126$ and then a bit smaller for $n = 127$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you please tell me how the negative sign came on the left side as you took the logarithm?

Comment: @BernhardListing : $\log_2 \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^n = \log_2 2^{-n} = -n \log_2 2 = -n$.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, a bit of arithmetic:

Note: $2^{10} =1024 > 10^3$,  and $2^7 =128 > 10^2$.

Hence :

$2^{120} \gt 10^{36}$, and

$2^{120}×2^7 > 10^{36}×10^{2}$,

$2^{127} > 10^{38}$, or

$10^{-38} > 2^{-127}=(0.5)^{127}.$